# creating a wxpython scrolled window (frame) by an event

Tags: python, wxpython, scrolledwindow

I am trying to create a new frame in a wxpanel by clicking a button.

Below is my code.
It does not work.
Scroll bars do not show up.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

(update: A button is added in the new window)

```
import wx

class ftest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "test Panel", size=(800, 500), pos=(0,0))
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, pos=(50,100), label="New Frame")
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newFrame)

    def newFrame(self, event):
        self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', size=(500, 500), pos=(800,0))
        self.new_window.Show()
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1)
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.new_window, pos=(50,100), label="button2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ftest()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

,

(update 2)
based on Joran Beasley's code,

this code creates scroll bars, but the button2 is not shown.
and the text widget does not work properly when scrolled.

```
import wx

class ftest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "test Panel", size=(800, 500), pos=(0,0))
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, pos=(50,100), label="New Frame")
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newFrame)

    def newFrame(self, event):
        self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', pos=(800,0))
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1,size=(500,500))
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
        self.new_window.Layout()
        self.new_window.Fit()
        self.new_window.Show()
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.new_window, pos=(50,100), label="button2")
        wx.StaticText(self.new_window, -1, 'test text', pos=(50, 200))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ftest()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

,

(update 3)
I found my mistake. The widgets should be on the scroll object, not on the frame object.
Layout() and Fit() are not required.
so correct code is

```
import wx

class ftest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                          "test Panel", size=(800, 500), pos=(0,0))
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, pos=(50,100), label="New Frame")
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newFrame)

    def newFrame(self, event):
        self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', pos=(800,0),size=(500,500))
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1)
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
        #self.new_window.Layout()
        #self.new_window.Fit()
        self.new_window.Show()
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.scroll, pos=(50,100), label="button2")
        wx.StaticText(self.scroll, -1, 'test text', pos=(50, 200))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ftest()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you explain "does not work"?

Comment: your code works fine for me, meaning that it pops up a window labeled 'test Panel', with a button on it labeled 'New Frame'.  When the button is clicked, a new window labeled 'frame2' appears

Comment: It opens a new frame, but no scroll bars. I cannot upload images here. so I put my image in my google drive. please click this, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FAgE3R3ldRck4xM2UtY3htZ28/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the scrollbars are there ... you just cant see them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def newFrame(self, event):
    self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', size=(500, 500), pos=(800,0))

    self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1)
    self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
    self.new_window.Layout()
    self.new_window.Fit()
    self.new_window.Show()
```

you need to layout the new window ... since you clearly want it to fill the 500,500 area you will need to use sizers

```
def newFrame(self, event):
    self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', size=(500, 500), pos=(800,0))
    sz = wx.BoxSizer()
    sz.SetMinSize((500,500)) #force minimum size
    self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1)
    sz.Add(self.scroll,1,wx.EXPAND)
    self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
    self.new_window.SetSizer(sz)
    self.new_window.Layout()
    self.new_window.Fit()
    self.new_window.Show()
```

or just force the size of the contained scrollwindow (which is what you normally do for scrolled windows)

```
def newFrame(self, event):
    self.new_window = wx.Frame(self, title='frame2', pos=(800,0))

    self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.new_window, -1,size=(500,500))
    self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1400)
    self.new_window.Layout()
    self.new_window.Fit()
    self.new_window.Show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It creates a window with scroll bars, but the size is not (500,500), and if I add a button, self.btn2 = wx.Button(self.new_window, pos=(50,100), label="button2") just below your code, it becomes broken again.

Comment: see new edit ... that should force it to fill the space

Comment: Thanks for your 2nd answer!, but if I add a button object, it behaves weird when I scroll it.

Comment: what do you mean? anyway thats probably best for another question

Comment: If I add a button and scroll it vertically, it becomes, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5FAgE3R3ldRX0s2eTJDekY4S1E/view?usp=sharing , the button does not stay  at a fixed position :(

Comment: and if I add a button after 'self.new_window.Show()', it does not show up.